# How to generate MD5 key hash for release?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, hash, md5

This command does not generate MD5 hash. I get only SHA1 and SHA256

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

How to generate MD5?
I have tried and still the same:
`gradle signingreport`
`/.gradlew signingreport`

```
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

I am using this method

```
keytool -exportcert -alias myaliasofkeystore -keystore mykeystorefolder/release-keystore | openssl md5
```

It gives me my md5, but is it correct?
output is:

```
MD5(stdin)= mymd5 without : like when generating singingreport
```

What stdin mean here?

Answer (score 2):

It is posssible that the command "keytool -list" does not show the MD5 hash by default. However, you can try adding the "-v" option to the command, which will display all available information about the certificate, including the MD5 hash.

So the updated command would be:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Regarding the method you tried with opensl, the "stdin" in the output means that the MD5 hash is being calculated from the standard input stream of the openssl comand, which in this case is the certficate exported by keytool..

There are a few other things you can try...

Try running the "keytool" command with the "-v" option to get more information about the certificate, including the MD5 hash. The command would be:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Try using the "jarsigner" command to get the MD5 hash...

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list my_application.apk
```

Replace "my_application.apk" with the path to your APK file the MD5 hash should be listed under the **Certificate fingerprints** section of the output..

---

If you still having trouble getting the MD5 hash using the keytool and openssl commands you could try using a different tool or method to calculate the hash. You could try using the "jarsigner" command as I suggested earlier, or you could try using an online tool to calculate the MD5 hash.

Alternatively, you could try generating a new debug keystore and see if that resolves the issue:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This will create a new debug keystore named **debug.keystore** in the current directory with the alias "androiddebugkey". You can then use the **keytool** and **openssl** commands to get the MD5 hash of this new keystore and see if it works correctly.

Comment: If I log with "stdin" in output it means it is incorrect? As you can see I have tried your advice with -v in the first line I have written about it. And still it does not gives me MD5.

Comment: If you're getting "stdin" in the output, it means that the MD5 hash is being calculated from the standard input stream of the openssl command. This is not necessarily incorrect, but the output format may be different from what you're expecting.

The "stdin" output means that openssl is reading the certificate data from the standard input stream, which in this case is the certificate exported by the keytool command. This is a valid way to calculate the MD5 hash of a certificate, but the output format may not be what you're used to seeing.